# Escribir dos matrices en archivo .txt en C

Tags: c

estoy aprendiendo a escribir en archivos en C y estoy atascado en un problema. La cosa es que tengo dos matrices y quiero escribir en un archivo todos los números distintos de 0 por cada fila y columna de cada matriz. Es algo sencillo pero hay una parte que aún no logro solucionar. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
FILE *fichero;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int matriz1[3][3] = {{1,2,0},
                     {1,1,0},
                     {1,0,0},};

int matriz2[3][3] = {{1,5,5},
                     {1,5,5},
                     {1,5,5},};
fichero = fopen("salida.txt","w");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        if (matriz1[i][j]!=0)
        {
            fprintf(fichero,"%d ",matriz1[i][j]);
        }
        else if (matriz2[i][j]!=0)
        {
            fprintf(fichero,"%d ",matriz2[i][j]);
        }
    }
    if (matriz1[i][j]!=0)
    {
        fprintf(fichero,"\n");
    }
}
fclose(fichero);
return 0;
}
```

el cual me escribe lo siguiente:

```
1 2 5 
1 1 5 
1 5 5
```

y lo que quiero obtener es:

```
1 2 1 5 5
1 1 1 5 5
1 1 5 5
```

He intentado corrigiendo y moviendo los indices de las matrices pero no encuentro una solución que funcione para todos los casos, también creo estar usando mal los ciclos for. Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con este problemita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los ciclos están bien, pero ese `if( ) { ... } else { ... }` está definitivamente mal puesto. Tal y como lo tienes, o imprimes el valor de una `matriz` o el de la otra ... y luego guardas si o si el valor de `matriz1` ...

Una posible solución es:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
  const int matriz1[3][3] = {
    {1,2,0},
    {1,1,0},
    {1,0,0}
  };
  const int matriz2[3][3] = {
    {1,5,5},
    {1,5,5},
    {1,5,5}
  };
  FILE *fichero = fopen( "salida.txt", "w" );

  for( int fila = 0; fila < 3; ++fila ) {
    for( int col = 0; col < 3; ++col ) if( matriz1[fila][col] ) fprintf( fichero, "%d ", matriz1[fila][col] );
    for( int col = 0; col < 3; ++col ) if( matriz2[fila][col] ) fprintf( fichero, "%d ", matriz2[fila][col] );
    fprintf( fichero, "\n" );
  }

  fclose( fichero );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh! ya veo mi error... muchísimas gracias me ha servido un montón!

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que lo que buscas hacer es concatenar y filtrar los valores de la matrices, entonces, sin modificar mucho tu código, podría quedar así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

FILE *fichero;

// Constantes que definen el tamaño de las matrices y 
// controlan las iteraciones de los ciclos "for"
const int FILS = 3;
const int COLS = 3;

int matriz1[FILS][COLS] = {
    {1,2,0},
    {1,1,0},
    {1,0,0}
};

int matriz2[FILS][COLS] = {
    {1,5,5},
    {1,5,5},
    {1,5,5}
};

fichero = fopen("salida.txt","w");

// Iteramos sobre las filas (de arriba a abajo)
for (int i = 0; i < FILS; ++i)
{
    // Iteramos sobre la columnas de la primer matriz (izquierda a derecha)
    for( int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j )
    {
        // Si el valor de la celda acual es diferente de 0, se escribe
        if (matriz1[i][j]!=0)
        {
            fprintf(fichero,"%d ",matriz1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Iteramos sobre la columnas de la segunda matriz (izquierda a derecha)
    for( int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j )
    {
        // Si el valor de la celda acual es diferente de 0, se escribe
        if (matriz2[i][j]!=0)
        {
            fprintf(fichero,"%d ",matriz2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Al final de cada fila se escribe un salto de linea
    fprintf(fichero,"\n");
}

fclose(fichero);
return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, te recomendaría encapsular el código dentro de una función. Así podrías generalizar el código para que funcione con matrices de tamaño "M x N". Solo que habría que tocar algunos tópicos como el uso de punteros y el calculo del indice en base a las filas y columnas; tópicos que no son precisamente los más fáciles. De todas formas te dejo un ejemplo que intenté hacer lo mas sencillo posible:

```
// Indéntica a "stdio.h" pero con seguriad de tipos y otras mejoras
#include <cstdio>

// Prototipo de la función:
// le indica al compilador el tipo y el orden de los argumentos que necesita la función
void concatena_y_guarda( int *matriz1, int *matriz2, const int FIILS, const int COLS );

int main(){


// Constantes que definen el tamaño de las matrices y 
// controlan las iteraciones de los ciclos "for"
const int FILS = 3;
const int COLS = 3;

// calculamos el tamaño del arreglo en base a las filas y columnas
int matriz1[ FILS * COLS ] = {
    1,2,0,
    1,1,0,
    1,0,0
};

// calculamos el tamaño del arreglo en base a las filas y columnas
int matriz2[ FILS * COLS ] = {
    1,5,5,
    1,5,5,
    1,5,5
};

// se realiza la llamada a la funcion y se le suministran
// los dos arreglos (matriz1 y matriz2) y,
// las dos dimenciones (FILS y COLS).
concatena_y_guarda( matriz1, matriz2, FILS, COLS );

return 0;
}


void concatena_y_guarda( int *matriz1, int *matriz2, const int FILS, const int COLS )
{
FILE *fichero;

fichero = fopen("salida.txt","w");

// Iteramos sobre las filas (de arriba a abajo)
for (int i = 0; i < FILS; ++i)
{
    // Iteramos sobre la columnas de la primer matriz (izquierda a derecha)
    for( int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j )
    {
        // Calculamos el indice: (fila actua * numero de columnas) + columna actual
        int indice = (i * COLS) + j;

        // Si el valor de la celda acual es diferente de 0, se escribe
        if (matriz1[indice]!=0)
        {
            fprintf(fichero,"%d ",matriz1[indice]);
        }
    }

    // Iteramos sobre la columnas de la segunda matriz (izquierda a derecha)
    for( int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j )
    {
        // Calculamos el indice: (fila actua * numero de columnas) + columna actual
        int indice = (i * COLS) + j;

        // Si el valor de la celda acual es diferente de 0, se escribe
        if (matriz2[indice]!=0)
        {
            fprintf(fichero,"%d ",matriz2[indice]);
        }
    }

    // Al final de cada fila se escribe un salto de linea
    fprintf(fichero,"\n");
}

fclose(fichero);
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda cualquiera de las dos soluciones.

Comment: Tienes razón en lo de crear la función... creo que empezaré a practicar con ello y con el tema de punteros, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda me ha servido mucho para comprender mi error!